# How to stop playback using MediaProtocolMessageStream

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I'm using `MediaProtocolMessageStream` and I'm able to pause (stop method call) and resume just fine however I do not know how to stop playback. Essentially I want the user to be able to stop the video that is playing and return to the initial screen of the application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question, your receiver application has a "landing" page and a "content page". Once the application is launched, you see the landing page on TV. When you start playing the content, you show the content. If you are asking how you can go back to your landing page after you are done with your content page, the answer is that there is no specific API on the SDK side that would/could do that for you since the SDK api's do not know about your receiver presentation at all; they mainly provide a communication channel for you to send messages or media commands/events back and forth and how you want to interpret or control your presentation is up to you. In terms of "stopping" the media playback, there is only a pause command (i.e no "stop"), same as the MediaElement api's.

You can achieve what you want by sending a (custom) command to your receiver and providing the appropriate handling of that on your receiver's page via javascript in a way you desire. Or you can purely code something on your receiver by listening to your MediaElement's events and  after receiving an "ended" event from your MediaElement, move to the landing page.